# Math with 5 Star Rating and Width

Tags: math, html, width

Right Now I have a 5 star rating with values ranging from 1-5. Behind these empty stars is a box whose width will be depending on the values of the votes. The width of the 5 stars = 150px. This means that if two people vote both with 2.5 stars I want the width of the background div to be 75px and so on. Anyone have an equation to go by?

Comment: This is more of a math question than a programming question.  Anyway, product of the average number of stars and the width of each star is what you are looking for. (averageStars * widthOfStar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var width = stars * 30;
```

:)

shouldn't 3-stars have a width of 90, not 75?

Comment: Your right. That shows how good @ math I am. 2.5 = 75px width :S